# *** Warning: WARN_GEN_CFA_UNSUPPORTED: in specman , why do i get it, and what does it mean?

Tags: specman

I have this code:

```
<' 
type type_t:[GOOD,BAD];
    struct packet {
    t:type_t;
    !header:uint(bits:3);  
};
extend sys {
    !pkt:packet;
    keep read_only(pkt.t==GOOD) => pkt.header==6;
    run() is also {
        gen pkt;
        gen pkt.header;
        print pkt;
    };        
  };
'>
```

And when i run it , i get this weird warning, when i try to generate pkt.header:

```
   *** Warning: WARN_GEN_CFA_UNSUPPORTED: 
The following constraint-from-above includes input(s) which cannot be sampled
during the allocation of packet-@1.
        keep read_only(pkt.t == GOOD) => pkt.header == 6    at line 9 in @gen
Enforcing the constraint through later sampling of these inputs is not
supported yet, and therefore it will not be enforced in the following
gen-action.

                at line 12 in @gen
        gen pkt.header;
```

This error message i weird, since when i issue 'gen pkt.header' , pkt is allready generated (allocated), and so is 't'.

I would appreciate it if some one could exaplain this to me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out your code after reading more about CFAs and it does seem that something fishy is going on in Specman. Like Hannes said, it's probably a bug.

Comment: fact is , the code works fine, header does equal 6 after this code is simulated. so i am not sure that what you are saying is correct.
also, notice that the warning is actually refering to the input, and not the target field which is being generated. so there is somnething weird going on with the input... why?

Comment: You're right, I changed my answer after a bit more research.

Answer (score 1):

This does indeed look strange. Especially if you turn on trace generation. Among others, the log shows this:

-> 0 #GEN> solving connected field set #12 of gen-action #3: (in sys-@1.pkt.header)

```
    pkt.header
```

-> 0 #GEN> reducing:

```
    pkt.header -> [6]
    due to constraints:
    keep read_only(pkt.t == GOOD) => pkt.header == 6    at line 10 in @cfa_depr

            **with the input state:**

    read_only(pkt.t == GOOD): TRUE
```

-> 0 #GEN> completed solution for connected fields: (in sys-@1.pkt.header)

```
    pkt.header: 6
    constrained by:
    keep read_only(pkt.t == GOOD) => pkt.header == 6    at line 10 in @cfa_depr
```

This might be a bug, I'll check with the developers.

Answer (score 1):

First, the header field is denoted with '`!`' which is a do-not-generate field, removing that and the warning will disappear.
If pkt was not generated prior to having pkt.header generated, you would probably hit an OS11 error for trying to access un-allocated memory area.
Second, the line:

```
keep read_only(pkt.t==GOOD) => pkt.header==6;
```

Should probably reside inside the struct itself (either with a '`soft`' or without it).

Comment: you are refering to the do-not-generate field itself..
however, the warning is refering to the input, and it tells me that it cannot be sampled... the warning is issued when i try to generate pkt.header, why can't the input be sampled at that point if i allready generated pkt?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior in the testcase is indeed a bug. The warning should not be issued in this scenario. There is an available patch for the issue which can be received from Cadence support.

For general details regarding constraints from above and specifically this warning, you can consider Specman documentation (section 1.10 in Specman Generation User Guide).